# Seemingly quick filter field-lookup is slow

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-queryset, django-filter

My rough model:

```
class m_Interaction(models.Model):
    fk_ip = models.ForeignKey('m_IP', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="interactions")
    fk_query = models.ForeignKey('m_Query', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="interactions")
```

Database used: SQLite

---

If I execute this query-set

```
m_Interaction.objects.filter(fk_query=None).filter(fk_ip__in=user.ips.all()).select_related('fk_query')
```

it takes 5 seconds.

If I remove the `filter(fk_query=None)` statement, the remaining query-set

```
m_Interaction.objects.filter(fk_ip__in=user.ips.all()).select_related('fk_query')
```

executes in only 100 milliseconds.

Shouldn't be the `filter(fk_ip__in=user.ips.all())` much more expensive? Or at least why is the `filter(fk_query=None)` statement so slow? It should be a simple "comparison with Null"-lookup.

---

SQL-Query with `filter(fk_query=None)`:

```
SELECT "data_manager_m_interaction"."id", 
       "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_ip_id", 
       "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_query_id",
       "data_manager_m_query"."id", 
       "data_manager_m_query"."fk_ip_id" 
FROM "data_manager_m_interaction" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "data_manager_m_query" 
ON ("data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_query_id" = "data_manager_m_query"."id") 
WHERE ("data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_ip_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "data_manager_m_ip" U0 WHERE U0."fk_user_id" = 1339) 
  AND "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_query_id" IS NULL) 
ORDER BY "data_manager_m_interaction"."timestamp" ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

SQL-Query without `filter(fk_query=None)`:

```
SELECT "data_manager_m_interaction"."id", 
       "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_ip_id", 
       "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_query_id", 
       "data_manager_m_query"."id", 
       "data_manager_m_query"."fk_ip_id" 
FROM "data_manager_m_interaction" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "data_manager_m_query" 
ON ("data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_query_id" = "data_manager_m_query"."id") 
WHERE "data_manager_m_interaction"."fk_ip_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "data_manager_m_ip" U0 WHERE U0."fk_user_id" = 1339) 
ORDER BY "data_manager_m_interaction"."timestamp" ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

---

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN (with filter):

```
[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_interaction USING INDEX data_manager_m_interaction_c50f4040 (fk_query_id=?)'), 
(0, 0, 0, 'EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1'), 
(1, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_ip AS U0 USING COVERING INDEX data_manager_m_ip_f569ccde (fk_user_id=?)'), 
(0, 1, 1, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_query USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)'), 
(0, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY')]
```

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN (without filter)

```
[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_interaction USING INDEX data_manager_m_interaction_c669518a (fk_ip_id=?)'), 
(0, 0, 0, 'EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1'), 
(1, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_ip AS U0 USING COVERING INDEX data_manager_m_ip_f569ccde (fk_user_id=?)'), 
(0, 1, 1, 'SEARCH TABLE data_manager_m_query USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)'), 
(0, 0, 0, 'USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY')]
```

Comment: First, you could try `filter(fk_query__isnull=True)` instead of `fk_query=None` and see if that improves anything, but I would do `print your-query.query` to see the raw sql statement and see the difference.

Comment: I agree that it seems counterintuitive. Does it make any difference if you change the order of the filters or combine them into a single filter? `filter(fk_query=None, fk_ip__in=user.ips.all())`

Comment: are you using mysql? i suspect you are. If so this result isn't surprising actually.

Comment: Thanks for  the fast replies! I updated my Question.
@Shang Wang `filter(fk_query__isnull=True)` made no difference.
The raw queries are listed above.
@Håken Lid order doesnt matter
@e4c5 I'm using SQLite, even worse :) but that shouldn't be the problem in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with sqlite and mysql is that they can use only one index per table as mentioned at https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

> Each table in the FROM clause of a query can use at most one index
>   (except when the OR-clause optimization comes into play) and SQLite
>   strives to use at least one index on each table

And it get's worse because sqlite query parser transforms the ON condition to a WHERE clause. Even without the `IS NULL` your `WHERE` clause is rather heavy. And it get's worse because you have an order by.

> SQLite attempts to use an index to satisfy the ORDER BY clause of a
>   query when possible. When faced with the choice of using an index to
>   satisfy WHERE clause constraints or satisfying an ORDER BY clause,
>   SQLite does the same cost analysis described above and chooses the
>   index that it believes will result in the fastest answer.

In many situations mysql can use another index for the order by but sqlite cannot. Postgresql, arguably the best open source RDBMS can use multiple indexes on each table.

So in short there is no way that sqlite can use an index for your `IS NULL` comparison. using `EXPLAIN` on the query would reveal that the available index is used on `fk_ip_id`

**Edit**:
I am not as proficient on sqlite explain output as I am on postgresql or mysql, but from what I understand of it shows that each table uses one index as discussed above. The `data_manager_m_ip` table is the one that makes the best use of indexes. There the table itself isn't even looked at all data is retrieved from the index itself.

The explain also does show that the index on fk_query_id is used. However my understanding is that this is used for the join. The explain also shows that there isn't any usage of indexes for the sorting. Can you post the explain for the other query as well.

**Edit 2**:
There you are, it's hazardous to optimize without looking at `EXPLAIN`. We were guessing at it was the is null comparison that's slow. but it's not!!  When you do the `IS NULL` comparison, sqlite uses the index for that but the `IN` clause is now without an index and that makes it horribly slow!!

Solution: You need a composite index for `fk_query_id, fk_ip_id` you can use django [index_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#index-together) to make one.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed anser, but does it explain the bad performance of `filter(fk_query=None)`? If I only leave this, and remove the `filter(fk_ip__in=user.ips.all())`-part it also performs bad. 
But could this be, because I didn't build a index for the fk_query-field?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret this, but to me it seems like SQLite is searching for interactions filtered by query=null using an index. Then it filters the result by the ips, also with an index and so on. So everything seems fine to me

Comment: do I have to reindex everything? I added `index_together = ["fk_query", "fk_ip"]` to the model and did a `makemigrations` and `migrate`. It took like 5 minutes to migrate, so I thought it created the index, but the query itself is still slow. Also there is no change in the `explain`-query, should there be a change?

Comment: because only one index can be used on a table. If one is used for IS NULL the other test will not have an index.

Comment: I really tried to fix it, but its still not working. I even created two compound indices, just for testing: `index_together = [["fk_ip", "fk_query"],["fk_query", "fk_ip"]]` But it uses neither of them. Its still the same `explain query` as written in the question. Also for me seems like it uses an index everytime. The normal one for the `is null`-lookup and this "covering" one for the `in`-lookup

Comment: yes. I even looked at the migration itself and saw that the indices were created.
I mean I have roughly 7million "interactions" in the database. and a lot of them have "null" at their "fk_query" field. But this shouldnt be a problem, because if its using the index, it can simpy lookup all the interactions with `fk_query=null`.

Comment: This question is becoming like a UN session :-) shall we close this and have a new question? After all the original question of why has been answered. Now it's a matter of how to solve which is proving to be a bit lengthy. Please post a new one give the indexes you have newly created and the new explains. thanks

Comment: great! did you post a follow up question?